# getting all options from select multiple tag to the backend

Tags: javascript, html, jstl

I am dynamically populating a select multiple tag in the ui based on certain user inputs. I want to get all the option values in this tag back at the backend. Currently I am finding that only the selected options in the select multiple list are gettable in the backend. Any ideas how i can get all the options (both selected and non selected) back?

Comment: Where do they come from when populating the select box for the first time? Why not get them from the same place?

Answer (score 1):

By submiting a form you will always get **ONLY** a selected options. The solution you need is propably on the place where you are populating that select. Place HIDDEN input under your select and populate it too with all values (separated with a semicolon for example).